# Did Spring data elasticsearch 5.4 can be worked with Elasticsearch 5.3?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I didn't found spring data elasticsearch for elasticsearch 5.3 . Can I use spring-data-elasticsearch for 5.4 directly?

Comment: According to [their github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch), Spring Data Elasticsearch `3.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` supports ElasticSearch 5.4.

Comment: I used elasticsearch5.3 . do you know Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT support elasticsearch 5.3？

Comment: Since it is the same major version I assume it'll work.

Comment: OK Thank you anyway.